Correctly escape environment variable to be used in Jenkins jq script
I have the following JSON:
{
  "defaultOptions" : {
    "environmentVariableEntries" : [
      {
        "key" : "OS_VERSION",
        "value" : "13"
      }
    ]
  }
}

on Jenkins I have a step that writes some environment variables and in another step I need to insert those variables to environmentVariableEntries in the json above,
here is my code:
sh(script: "echo \$(jq --arg url \"$URL\" '.defaultOptions.environmentVariableEntries += [{\"key\": \"URL\", \"value\": \$url}]' json.xctestplan) > json.xctestplan", returnStdout: true)

this kind of works but have 2 issues:

it adds \n to the end of the replaced URL
In some cases (special character ?) it throws:

++ jq --arg url 'https://redacted
' '.defaultOptions.environmentVariableEntries += [{"key": "URL", "value": [$url]}]' json.xctestplan
jq: parse error: Invalid string: control characters from U+0000 through U+001F must be escaped at line 2, column 1
+ echo

I tried to wrap the variable in [] without success.

Your variable URL contains the newline. How do you set it?

I set it like this env.URL = sh(script: "aws ssm get-parameter --name token_url --profile profile --region us-east-1 --with-decryption | jq -r .Parameter.Value", returnStdout: true)

Why you need echo? It may be much easier without it.

Are you using echo to enable you to write to the json.xctestplan file in the same command? Simply redirecting the output from jq will result in an empty output file.

Can you give an example of a URL that causes the error relating to control characters. You can obfuscate it appropriately so that you don't leak any sensitive information.

Let's first establish that the jq command works.
#!/bin/bash

URL=https://www.google.com

jq --arg url "$URL" '.defaultOptions.environmentVariableEntries += [{"key": "URL", "value": $url}]' json.xctestplan

The output is:
{
  "defaultOptions": {
    "environmentVariableEntries": [
      {
        "key": "OS_VERSION",
        "value": "13"
      },
      {
        "key": "URL",
        "value": "https://www.google.com"
      }
    ]
  }
}

So that appears to be doing what you want.
I think I understand why you are wrapping your jq command in an echo command. Is that to allow you to redirect to the same file that you're reading from? Without the echo the input file would be truncated before reading commences.
How about updating your Jenkins command to something like this (untested):
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    environment {
        URL = 'https://www.google.com'
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('Update XCTestPlan') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh "jq --arg url \"$URL\" '.defaultOptions.environmentVariableEntries += [{\"key\": \"URL\", \"value\": \$url}]' json.xctestplan > json.xctestplan.tmp"
                    sh "mv json.xctestplan.tmp json.xctestplan"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

That enables you to avoid using echo and so simplifies the quoting.
As a possible refinement you could combine the two sh commands using the && operator.

I have one more case where the env var is a json like this:
export ADMIN_API_CREDS='{"name": "some (name)", "clientId":"some|var","password":"some|pwd", "created":"2020-11-05T19:04:07.529606Z","tenant": "some-value"}'
same sh is now failing with syntax error near unexpected token ('so I think the json needs to be escaped somehow ? I tried withjq -r` with same result
